# Javascript - Flatten nested arrays of objects. Make it pretty?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on formatting a set of data into one array to use for a table. I have a data set like this

```
data = [{
  hello: 'world',
  children: [{
    foo: 'bar'
  }]
}]
```

I am looking to get this data into one array while marking all of the parent nodes with a `parent: true` bool. So I can throw it all into a table but still have a differentiating factor between a parent and child. I know I can just loop twice for the table but I am doing this for reusability purposes. I have a working block of code below.

```
  formattedData (data) {
    const formattedData = []
    data.map(dataPoint => {
      let obj = dataPoint
      obj['parent'] = true
      formattedData.push(dataPoint)
      if (dataPoint.children) {
        dataPoint.children.map(c => {
          formattedData.push(c)
        })
      }
    })
    return formattedData
  }
```

Resulting data looks like this:

```
data = [{
  hello: 'world', 
  parent: true
}, {
  foo: 'bar'
}]
```

Just checking to see if there is a better/more efficient/prettier way to do this (or if the way I did it is how it should be done). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use `.map` if you aren't going to use the mapped array - use `forEach` for generic side-effect iteration. Also, probably best not to use the same name for the function *and* the array you're pushing to. You might consider a recursive `reduce` if there can be further levels of nesting

Comment: If you’re not going to use the return value of `map` (which is what it exists to create), use `forEach` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you meant to copy the object with `let obj = dataPoint` to not mutate the argument passed to the function and the object is a simple `Object`, you can use object spread to copy it and add a property
- [`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) exists now (and can be made backwards-compatible with shims like everything else)
- Why is it a class method if it doesn’t use `this`?

```
const getFormattedData = data =>
  data.flatMap(dataPoint => [
    {...dataPoint, parent: true},
    ...dataPoint.children || [],
  ])
```

Or, if you also wanted to remove the `children` property:

```
const getFormattedData = data =>
  data.flatMap(({children, ...dataPoint}) => [
    {...dataPoint, parent: true},
    ...children || [],
  ])
```

Comment: Thanks! +1 for option to remove children. I did not know about flatmap!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a single [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and some ES6 destructuring:

```js
const data = [{ hello: 'world', children: [{ foo: 'bar' }], }, { hello: 'world2' }]

const result =  data.reduce((r, {children, ...other}) => {
  if(children){
    r.push(Object.assign({}, other, {parent: true}))
    r.push(...children)  
  } else r.push(Object.assign({}, other))
  return r 
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

If however you have further `children` levels then you would have to use a `recursive` approach but based on the input data that does not seem to be the case.

You can also shorten if further if you are not concerned about `readability`:

```js
const data = [{ hello: 'world', children: [{ foo: 'bar' }], }, { hello: 'world2' }]

const result =  data.reduce((r, {children, ...other}) => {
  r.push(Object.assign({}, other, children ? {parent: true} : {}))
  children ? r.push(...children) : null
  return r 
}, [])

console.log(result)
```